# in a way that everyone will understand

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> There are a few general principles that apply to all the kinds of teaching. The first principle is that the teacher should be clear. Whatever you are teaching, teach clearly. Discover what your students do not know and then try to explain it to them ***in a way that*** everyone will ***understand***.

Is the verb "understand" above an intransitive verb (a verb that doesn't allow a direct object), where "that" being a relative **adverb** and the part "explain it to them *in a way that* everyone will understand" meaning "explain it to them in a way *in which*, or *in such a way that*, everyone will understand (≒'understand whatever you are teaching')"?

Or is it a transitive verb, where "a way" being the object of the verb ("everyone will understand *a way*"), "that" being a relative **pronoun**, and the same part meaning "explain it to them in a way *which* everyone will understand" instead?

Comment: I'd say the cited usage is unquestionably ***transitive***, if only because I can't see any problem in appending the word "it" to the final sentence (which simply echoes preceding "explain **it** to them"). I can't really see how choosing between the two labels "transitive" and "intransitive" in this context helps you to understand English, though,

Comment: If transitive, is the object of the verb "it" (=whatever you are teaching) or "a way" (in the former case the object is to be omitted, whereas in the latter the object is the antecedent in front of "that")?

Comment: As I said, you *could* append "it" to the example text, in which case that would unquestionably be the "object" of a "transitive" verb usage. Even if that extra word ***isn't*** present, the text still means exactly the same thing. I have no real interest in which way *you* decide to classify the usage ***syntactically***, because I can't see what use it is. To repeat my earlier point - *What practical difference does it make to you in terms of learning English?*

Comment: ...suppose we assume the implied "object" of ***understand*** in the example text is in fact ***you*** (which could *also* be appended to the existing text instead of my previous suggestion ***it***). That doesn't change the meaning of the text, but does it change your understanding of how English works?

Comment: I'm not primarily interested in whether the verb "understand" is used transitive or intransitive here *per se*. What I want to know is the nature of the word "that" in "in a way that...," and what is supposed be the object of the verb "understand," if there is at all, implicitly or explicitly. Is it ①"a way" or ②"whatever you are teaching" that "everyone will understand"?

Comment: If "you" could be the implied object, then the implied object could also be "whatever you are teaching," but the implied object could **NOT** be the explicit antecedent "a way/the way," right?

Comment: The object is actually "what your students do not know," I suppose.

Comment: The first definition in the full OED *(**transitive**)* is *To comprehend; to apprehend the meaning or import of; to grasp the idea of*, for which their two most recent citations are 1) *One half of the world cannot understand the pleasures of the other* and 2) *The young prince saw that they were in possession of something more divine than the world could understand.* There first ***intransitive*** definition is *To have comprehension or understanding (in general or in a particular matter)*, with example *She dwells on him with faithful eyes, ‘I cannot understand: I love’.* If that helps! :)

Comment: It is of course quite possible to say something like *I **understand the way** you are trying to explain quantum mechanics to me, but I don't actually understand quantum mechanics itself at all.* So ***in principle*** your example text could be classified as "ambiguous", in that the writer might simply be advising his readers to make sure their students ***fully understand the method*** by which they are being taught even if they have little or no understanding of the actual subject matter. But this is more about "playing with language" than it is about "learning English".

Comment: So it could be interpreted to mean the way of explanation as well as the materials themselves (or "you" or "it [=what your students do not know]") that is to be "understood" there, because of the ambiguous way the sentence is written?

Comment: Well, obviously in practice my point about ***fully understanding the method*** by which one is being instructed (but totally failing to understand the matter being taught) is ridiculously contrived. But it ***is*** at least possible for us both to understand the point being made there. On the other hand, I cannot even *begin* to conceive of any different meaning in *your* example, depending on whether we interpret ***understand*** as transitive or intransitive, and in the former case depending on whether it references ***you*** or ***it***. These are completely *meaningless* "distinctions".

Comment: I've got to say that 'He explained it in a way that everyone appreciated' and 'He explained it in a way that everyone could understand' are only equivalent structures on the surface. In the first, the appreciation is obviously for the method of teaching. But the thrust of the second is that the teaching was such that at the end of it, everyone (paying due attention) _did_ understand. I'd take it as a deleted form of 'He explained it in such a way that everyone could understand it'. (Reading @FF, I'm just saying the same thing in a slightly different ...

Comment: way). _But with deleted forms, trying to apply the normal rules is often unhelpful_. I'd say _understand_ is 'crypto-transitive' here (I bet few have ever come up with that coining), but fear I might just add to any confusion.

Comment: So while it is theoretically possible to stipulate it to mean "understand the teaching method only while utterly failing to understand the very content being taught," such a remote possibility of contrived interpretation aside, it's safer to take the part to mean either "understand you" or "understand it," the object of understanding being the content itself, or what you teach as a whole, including the content as well as the teaching method?